# Error in creating directive IONIC

Tags: ionic3

I am getting this error. please help

> Argument of type '{ selector: string; directives: (typeof HighlightDirective)[]; templateUrl: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'directives' does not exist in type 'Component'. (property) directives: (typeof HighlightDirective)[] Argument of type '{ selector: string; directives: (typeof HighlightDirective)[]; templateUrl: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'directives' does not exist in type 'Component'. (property) directives: (typeof HighlightDirective)[]

**ionic info:-**

cli packages: (/home/admin01/.nvm/v9.3.0/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-plugin-proxy : 1.5.6
@ionic/cli-utils        : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI)       : 3.19.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.5
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node : v9.3.0
npm  : 5.5.1
OS   : Linux 4.4
```

Environment Variables:

```
HTTP_PROXY       : not set
http_proxy       : http://proxyuser:pr0xyuser@192.168.0.11:3128
HTTPS_PROXY      : not set
https_proxy      : not set
IONIC_HTTP_PROXY : not set
PROXY            : not set
proxy            : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```